# Why can`t we treat SSL Certs like Pgp keys instead of trusting CAs?

Tags: security, internet, encryption, ssl, certificate

I am dumb and stupid and I do not know all the technical aspects of SSL and server/client side implications and implementations. However I understand them good enough from user point of view to use SSL and encyrption daily.

I was thinking that how silly it is to trust some unknown/known CAs when it comes to our our certificates for our servers. There had been many cases of misconduct, misuse, compromises and theft of certificates/ca keys from those places. On top of those known issues we also have to pay these guys regularly.

I am wondering why  can not we use/treat web server certificates like we use our pgp keys? So I sign a SSL certificate and send to a central server. And then each user accessing my site checks the validity and the keys from  some central server (like pgp key servers).

Is this a stupid idea? If so what could be a better idea than current system of issuing valid certificates. I am looking for a better than more secure idea. Naturally this is not a solution to an existing problem, rather it will be a hypothetical solution for some future implementation of a currently messed up web of trust on the internet due to recent news about NSA and their criminal buddies around the world.

thanks

Comment: PGP is built on a circle of trust CA's are built around a circle of trust what's the difference?  Who runs this "central server" and why should we trust this "central server" more than Microsoft, Apple, or any other CA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's convenience, mostly. A pure PGP-like web-of-trust only works if there *is* a path of trust between the verifying client and the signed certificate.

With PKI, it starts with the list of trusted root CAs that all operating systems (and often web browsers) have built in, and that list can be used to verify 99% of all server certificates encountered.

With WoT, each of your visitors would only see that the server's certificate is signed by one "yarun can", and they would need to either know someone who has already verified you, or find a way to verify your key themselves. This only *barely* works for email, where the connections are few and long-term (e.g. friends, coworkers). It wouldn't scale at all for hundreds of websites – even for visitors who *do* have a local security-conscious geek that they trust with verifying those sites.

But what if they don't? What if the visitor doesn't know anyone who'd have already verified your key? They would have to find a way to verify you directly. *You and dozens, hundreds of other webmasters.* Perhaps you'd find a visitor or two asking you for your fingerprint over the phone. The other several thousand would simply do nothing and just click through the "untrusted server" warnings.

End result: no security at all.

And if you're now thinking "let's have a list of trusted-by-default signers/verifiers"... you just implemented the same trusted-authority PKI on top of PGP.